# How do I increase the legend size on a correlation matrix made with ggcorrplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I'm trying to increase the legend size on a correlation matrix made using `ggcorrplot`. I would like the legend length to equal the height of the matrix, so it is readable in a presentation. I would like to keep the image export size where it is now. Does anybody know how to do that? I can't seem to find it on the help page.

Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

data <- mtcars
res1 <- cor(data)
png("cars_example.png", width=1000, height=700)
ggcorrplot(res1, hc.order = FALSE, type = "lower",
           outline.col = "white",
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray,
           colors = c("#6D9EC1", "white", "#E46726"),
           lab = TRUE, lab_size = 6, show.diag=FALSE,
           legend.title = "r-value", tl.cex=18)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Just add a `theme` argument to the `ggcorrplot` as in this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553544/how-to-increase-size-of-legend-in-ggplot2?rq=1